# Resources for learning domain theory?

Tags: mathematics-education, ct.category-theory

I'm a computer programmer who's caught on to denotational semantics. I mostly work with Ruby, JavaScript and C, but I know a little Haskell and ML. I've taken my first steps towards reasoning about what my software *means*, but my knowledge of domain theory is weak. DCPOs, chains, new notation – can you recommend a coherent introduction to this stuff?

Comment: Have you tried the references given in the Wikipedia article?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [book recommended by jef](https://mathoverflow.net/a/24677/49269) is the domain-theory bible. It may be a bit overwhelming for a beginner. For an easier and more compressed introduction I recommend that you have a look at Abramsky and Jung's chapter on domain theory from the Handbook of Logic in Computer Science. It is [available in PDF](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~axj/pub/papers/handy1.pdf) from [Achim's publications](https://www.cs.bham.ac.uk/~axj/papers.html) lits.

Answer (score 3):

*Semantics with Applications: An Appetizer* by Hanne Riis Nielson and Flemming Nielson provides a rudimentary introduction, also linking denotational semantics to program analysis via abstract interpretation. [*Plotkin's notes*](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/gdp/publications/Domains_a4.ps) are excellent, more comprehensive, and more theoretically bent.

Answer (score 2):

[http://www.amazon.com/exec/obidos/ASIN/0521803381/](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521803381)

I read this book for a course when I was an undergraduate and it is a very good introduction for all the things you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

Another good book that teaches the ropes of domain theory for a beginner is Thomas Streicher's "Domain-Theoretic Foundations of Functional Programming", World Scientific.
I highly recommend this book because of its clarity and rigour.  Please look up the link at http://www.worldscientific.com/worldscibooks/10.1142/6284 for information on this book.
The functional language it works with is a prototypical simply-typed lambda calculus, called PCF (Programming language for Computable Functionals).  The domain theory developed in it and the denotational semantics defined is systematic in its organization.

Answer (score 1):

I used the book *The Formal Semantics of Programming Languages* by G. Winskel for an undergraduate course, and I found it a reasonably good introduction to the topic; it also covers operational semantics and its relationship with denotational semantics, which I found quite enlightening since the former one is probably easier to grasp initially.

Answer (score 1):

I was in same situation from mathematic point of view and trying to understand the data semantics side of domain theory. I’ve read most of the books mentioned by others but I found a nicely written compact (only 70 pages) Notebook on domain theory. The names is Notes on Domain Theory and the writer is Viggo Stoltenberg-Hansen. I ready liked the way he start building up all notation of domain theory from data semantics view.
You can find it in the following link :

[Notes on domain theory](http://www2.math.uu.se/%7Ehamrin/dt04/DT01rev.pdf)